# C++ parameter pack with single type enforced in arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, variadic-templates, c++17

I want to be able to do the following:

```
#include <array>
struct blah { };

template<typename... Args>
constexpr auto foo(Args&&... args)
{
    return std::array<blah, sizeof...(Args)>{{ args... }};
}

auto res = foo({}, {});
```

The following answers aren't satisfying: they just want to check that the parameter pack is of a single type, but I want to convert the values right to it in the arguments (else it does not work).

[C++ parameter pack, constrained to have instances of a single type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38528801/c-parameter-pack-constrained-to-have-instances-of-a-single-type)

[Parameter with non-deduced type after parameter pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41262641/parameter-with-non-deduced-type-after-parameter-pack)

[Specifying one type for all arguments passed to variadic function or variadic template function w/out using array, vector, structs, etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703658/specifying-one-type-for-all-arguments-passed-to-variadic-function-or-variadic-te)

I also can't use initializer_list since I wouldn't be able to count the number of arguments to pass to the `array` type.
And I especially don't want to type `foo(blah{}, blah{});`.

What are my possibilities ?

Comment: For lazy people: https://ideone.com/bzjh00

Comment: (side-question: wasn't there ideone integration directly in stackoverflow at  some point in time ? I seem to remember being able to test-run c++ code directly in answers but maybe I've just dreamed...)

Comment: Never heard about that

Comment: I'm not sure what you want is possible as is. The compiler can't deduce what `{}` is and I'm not sure there is a way to do so. But, as usual, some C++ guru will come and prove me wrong by submitting a 10 meta functions based answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A little bit expanded [approach of Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47473109/4324224) for lazies (C++17):

```
#include <utility>
#include <array>

struct blah {};

template <class T, std::size_t I>
using typer = T;

template <class T, std::size_t N, class = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
struct bar_impl;

template <class T, std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
struct bar_impl<T, N, std::index_sequence<Is...>> {
    static auto foo(typer<T, Is>... ts) {
        return std::array<T, N>{{ts...}};
    }
};

template <class T = blah, std::size_t N = 10, class = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
struct bar;

template <class T, std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
struct bar<T, N, std::index_sequence<Is...>>: bar_impl<T, Is>... {
    using bar_impl<T, Is>::foo...;
};

int main() {
    bar<>::foo({}, {});
}
```

[[live demo]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/EmsANCXI3Uk6oiu8)

**Edit:**

Some C++14 solution which (as noted by max66) is even simpler than I expected:

```
#include <utility>
#include <array>

struct blah {};

template <class T, std::size_t I>
using typer = T;

template <class T = blah, std::size_t N = 10, class = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
struct bar;

template <class T, std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
struct bar<T, N, std::index_sequence<Is...>>: bar<T, N - 1> {
    using bar<T, N - 1>::foo;
    static auto foo(typer<T, Is>... ts) {
        return std::array<T, N>{{ts...}};
    }
};

template <class T>
struct bar<T, 0, std::index_sequence<>> {
    static auto foo() {
        return std::array<T, 0>{{}};
    }
};

int main() {
    bar<>::foo({}, {});
}
```

[[live demo]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zXqgQV7CEAhb5hhA)

**One more edit:**

This one (as suggested by Jarod42) provides exactly the same syntax for invocation as in OP's question:

```
#include <utility>
#include <array>

struct blah {};

template <class T, std::size_t I>
using typer = T;

template <class T = blah, std::size_t N = 10, class = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
struct bar;

template <class T, std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
struct bar<T, N, std::index_sequence<Is...>>: bar<T, N - 1> {
    using bar<T, N - 1>::operator();
    auto operator()(typer<T, Is>... ts) {
        return std::array<T, N>{{ts...}};
    }
};

template <class T>
struct bar<T, 0, std::index_sequence<>> {
    auto operator()() {
        return std::array<T, 0>{{}};
    }
};

bar<> foo;

int main() {
    foo({}, {});
}
```

[[live demo]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CZ5jZNGvHkdLpFNy)

Comment: If `bar` inherit recursively from `bar<T, N-1U>` and `foo()` is defined inside `bar`, you can avoid `bar_impl` and make this works also with C++14 (I suppose also C++11 with a surrogate for `std::index_sequence`)

Comment: awesome ! I honestly did not think that this was possible to do at all.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, if you can afford to change the syntax a **little** bit, this is the best I managed to find:

```
#include <array>

// to_array implementation taken from 
// http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/to_array
namespace detail {
template <class T, std::size_t N, std::size_t... I>
constexpr std::array<std::remove_cv_t<T>, N>
    to_array_impl(T (&a)[N], std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    return { {a[I]...} };
}
}

template <class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::array<std::remove_cv_t<T>, N> to_array(T (&a)[N])
{
    return detail::to_array_impl(a, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
// End of to_array implementation

struct blah { };

template<std::size_t N>
constexpr auto foo(const blah(&arr)[N])
{
    return to_array(arr);
}

int main()
{
    auto res = foo({{}, {}});
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, `foo({}, {})` became `foo({{}, {}})`.
Here is a working example: https://ideone.com/slbKi3

The issue with the way you want it (`foo({}, {})`) is that the compiler has no way to know what it is supposed to convert `{}` to.

I tried to find a way to let it know but it didn't listen at all.

Comment: Nice. But I suppose can be simplified: if you call immediately `to_array_impl()` from `foo()` (you know `N` in `foo()` so you can call `std::make_index_sequence<N>{}` from `foo()`) you can avoid the `to_array()` step.

Answer (score 2):

If you accept, as proposed by Telokis, to add a bracket level calling `foo()`

```
auto res = foo( { {}, {} } );
```

you can use the C-style array trick proposed by Telokis and a simple cycle to initialize the returned value

```
template <std::size_t N>
constexpr std::array<blah, N> foo (const blah(&arr)[N])
 {
   std::array<blah, N> ret;

   for ( auto i = 0U ; i < N ; ++i )
      ret[i] = arr[i];

   return ret;
 }
```

Unfortunately the `operator[]` for `std::array` is `constexpr` only starting from C++17, so the preceding `foo` is effectively `constexpr` only starting from C++17.

So you can call

```
auto res = foo( { {}, {} } );
```

also in C++11 and C++14, but

```
constexpr auto res = foo( { {}, {} } );
```

only starting from C++17.

Comment: instead of doing the for-loop by hand you can also use the experimental std::to_array which has a nice pack-expansion implementation: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/to_array

Comment: @Jean-MichaëlCelerier - sure, but it's the Telokis's anwser; my intention was propose something different.

Comment: you can `return std::array<blah, sizeof...(Indx)>{blah[Indx]...};` and make it C++11 compatible.

Answer (score 2):

One (limited) ways to keep your syntax is to have several overloads:

```
constexpr auto foo(const blah& a1)
{
    return std::array<blah, 1>{{ a1 }};
}

constexpr auto foo(const blah& a1, const blah& a2)
{
    return std::array<blah, 2>{{ a1, a2 }};
}

// ...

// Up to N
constexpr auto foo(const blah& a1, const blah& a2, .., const blah& aN)
{
    return std::array<blah, N>{{ a1, a2, .., aN }};
}
```

W.F. in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47470874/c-parameter-pack-with-single-type-enforced-in-arguments/47473376#47473376) shows a way to generate it thanks to variadic at class scope.

Comment: Isn't that the reason why variadic templates were invented?

Answer (score 2):

In C++17 you can use a combination of `static_assert` and `std::conjunction` like this:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>

struct blah {};

template <typename Arg, typename... Args>
constexpr auto foo_helper(Arg&& first, Args&&... rest) {
    
    static_assert(std::conjunction_v<std::is_same<Arg, Args>...>);
    
    return std::array<blah, 1 + sizeof...(Args)>{first, rest...};
}

template <typename... Args>
constexpr auto foo(Args&&... args) {
    return foo_helper(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

auto res = foo(blah{}, blah{})
```