# Variadic Function

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, variadic-functions, variadic

I am trying to write a class to represent a tensor `Tensor` and would like to provide the syntax `tensor(i, j)` for a 2 dimensional tensor, `tensor (i, j, k)` for a 3 dimensional tensor and so on.

What I want to know is if there is a c++ type safe way to declare such `Tensor:operator()(int, int, ...)` that accepts any number of `int` arguments (besides the C style with the macros `va_start va_end`) and how to use said arguments inside the function.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What about variadic template parameter packs?

Comment: You can use C++ variadic templates and constraint the argument to be of a specific type (or convertible to a specific type). Using the resulting parameter packs is a bit of a pain, though.

Comment: Is the tensors dimension a run-time property, or a compile-time one?

Comment: Sounds like you are reinventing `std::tuple`. If yours is not the same, at least you can steal implementation and design ideas from it.

Comment: @Raymond Chen tensor is essentially a vector or matrix or multidimensional array, not a set of different types. boost have MultiArray and Eigen library had  tensor type. Hmm, if change of dimensions  needed in run-time, this can be implemented with only variadic methods, in both case even tensor[i][j][k] form is possible (maybe a little easier with static dimensions)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could always use an ordinary parameter pack; but force a compilation failure unless all parameters are `int`s:

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>


class foo {

public:

    template<typename ...Args,
         typename=std::void_t<std::enable_if_t
                      <std::is_same_v<Args, int>>...>>
    void operator()(Args ...args)
    {
    }
};

void bar()
{
    foo bar;

    bar(4, 2);
}
```

That will compile, but not this:

```
bar(4, "foo");
```

or

```
bar(4, 2.3);
```

Note that this will not compile either:

```
unsigned baz=2;

bar(4, baz);
```

If you need to accept unsigned values, tweat the template accordingly.

Note that the template does not need to use a forwarding reference, since the only acceptable parameters are plain `int`s. Within the template function, you now have a garden-variety parameter pack, that you would use the same way you'd use any other parameter pack.

Comment: Also op could use `std::is_convertible` or something similar instead of `std::is_same`.

Answer (score 1):

To accept also `unsigned int` and other types that are convertible to `int`, and if you can accept an upper limit (63, in the following example) to the number of integer argument, I propose to follow [an example from W.F.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47470874/c-parameter-pack-with-single-type-enforced-in-arguments/47473376#47473376).

So you can develop a `typer`

```
template <typename T, std::size_t>
using typer = T;
```

and a recursive `struct proOp`

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N = 64U,
          typename = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
struct proOp;

template <typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
struct proOp<T, N, std::index_sequence<Is...>> : public proOp<T, N-1U>
 {
   using proOp<T, N-1U>::operator();

   void operator() (typer<T, Is>... ts)
    { }
 };

template <typename T>
struct proOp<T, 0U, std::index_sequence<>>
 {
   void operator() ()
    { }
 };
```

Inheriting from `proOp<int>`, `Tensor` become

```
struct Tensor : public proOp<int>
 {
   using proOp<int>::operator();
 };
```

The following is a full working example

```
#include <utility>

template <typename T, std::size_t>
using typer = T;

template <typename T, std::size_t N = 64U,
          typename = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
struct proOp;

template <typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
struct proOp<T, N, std::index_sequence<Is...>> : public proOp<T, N-1U>
 {
   using proOp<T, N-1U>::operator();

   void operator() (typer<T, Is>... ts)
    { }
 };

template <typename T>
struct proOp<T, 0U, std::index_sequence<>>
 {
   void operator() ()
    { }
 };

struct Tensor : public proOp<int>
 {
   using proOp<int>::operator();
 };

int main()
 {
   Tensor t;

   t(1, 2, 3);
   t(1, 2, 3, 4U); // accept also unsigned
   //t(1, "two"); // error
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way could be make `operator()` recursive and use the first argument in every recursion

```
   // recursive case
   template <typename ... Ts>
   void operator() (int i0, Ts ... is)
    {
      // do something with i0
      this->operator()(is...); // recursion
    }

   void operator() ()
    { }
```

The following is a full working example

```
struct Tensor
 {
   // recursive case
   template <typename ... Ts>
   void operator() (int i0, Ts ... is)
    {
      // do something with i0
      this->operator()(is...); // recursion
    }

   void operator() ()
    { }
 };

int main()
 {
   Tensor t;

   t(1, 2, 3);
   t(1, 2, 3, 4U); // accept also unsigned
   //t(1, "two"); // error
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a more laconic way for creating safe variadic function, without using recursion and std::enable_if:

```
template <typename ...Ints>
void function(int first, Ints... other)
{
    int values[] = {first, other...};
    for(int value : values)
    {
        //your code
    }
}
```

This way is also type safe and `function(1, "2", 3)` won't compile.